# Do dead dwellers require food and water?

Tags: fallout-shelter

After a vicious attack of radrochaesm several of my dwellers are dead and I have a resource problem with food and water.

Do my dwellers still consume food when they are dead? (They still count in the population count.)

If not then I think I'll let them be dead for a while longer. But if they do, I might as well wake them and put them to use.

Comment: You should revive them if you can, other dwellers don't like working around dead bodies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No they don't count as a dweller when they are dead but you should wake them up cause your dwellers happiness will rapidly go down if they see dead bodies